# what is the difference between {% if %} and {% ifequal }% in django?

Tags: django, django-templates

In django template I used both if and ifequal but didn't notice the difference between them. Is there any performance difference with both of them ?

Answer (score 6):

`{% ifequal a b %}` is just a shorthand syntax for `{% if a == b %}`. Do note that `ifequal` is considered obsolete and should not be used. [Django's docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#ifequal-and-ifnotequal).

Answer (score 0):

The important line of code from the source code for `ifequal` is the following from its underlying node

```
if (self.negate and val1 != val2) or (not self.negate and val1 == val2):
```

[Source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/defaulttags.py#L289)

This node also handles `ifnotequal` which is what the `self.negate` is for, but it in this case `negate` is false, so it just evaluates whether `val1` is equal to `val2`, the equivalent of `{% if val1 == val2 %}`.

The `if` is the equivalent of python's if statement where it can evaluate conditions to decide whether or not to display a context block